# How to access android native layout file from PCL Project in xamarin forms application?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to access this layout file from xamarin.android layout to my PCL project in xamarin forms application?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
    android:text="Unstyled Button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Styled Button" />
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: It's not suitable for me. It uses custom renderer and want access to this native file to my shared project.

Comment: You can not directly create an instance of an Android layout from a PCL/NetStd project

Answer (score 1):

[This is about PCL](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/), in this link we can see a picture like this:

[image]
The PCL just is a library which will be referenced in Android and IOS project.

> access this layout file from xamarin.android layout to my PCL project

This means you are in a library, and you want to get a object instance from a project which you will reference this library. It is sure that the library won't know anything about the project.

You can access the layout by [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/), but its implementation is in Android platform not PCL. And then use [LayoutInflater](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.LayoutInflater/) to inflate your layout file in Android, and do something you want to do.

### LayoutInflater

You can [refer to the `GetView` of ListView's adapter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/list-view/part-2-populating-a-list-view/).